# Android app navigation best practices

Tags: android

I am working on an android game. It will be similar to [this popular game](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nerdyoctopus.gamedots). My user has to navigate between various `activity`s. This can be implemented using either a system of `next` and `previous` buttons or using the swipe input. I can implement both methods. I want to know which method is more intuitive  and user friendly. Advantage of buttons is that it is explicit, user upon seeing the buttons will know how to navigate. In case  of swipe, user may not be able to figure out how to navigate to next screen. However, buttons consume space and need a lot of extra work to fit with the rest of the screen.

Comment: Both are effective, it depends on your user demographics and your app, explain what is this app used for and who are the target audience.

Comment: Please checkout the url i have just added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the main platform is a mobile where users are well aware of gestures. Plus you are targeting gamer community, I would suggest using swipe gesture as it is more fun than buttons.
I would suggest adding indications where the user is in this process

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feMzeM.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

. 
[Take a look at user on boarding Pocket review.](http://www.useronboard.com/how-pocket-onboards-new-users/)

Comment: the text `swipe to continue` , is that a textview or toast ? Will it matter if the text is not there ?

Comment: It will for a typical easier for user to understand what to do if there is a call to action, but I think the little circle navigation will be enough for user to understand.